# Magento 2.4.3 https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js 403

Tags: magento2.4.3, vimeo

I have added a Vimeo video in the product gallery and when I try to play it **on the product page it always gives**

```
f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

**Magento Version 2.4.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/frontend/web/js/fotorama-add-video-events.js file and replace https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js with https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js

Then deploy static contents and Hopefully this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js with https://f.vimeocdn.com/js_opt/froogaloop2.min.js
This seems to be the new URL of this JS.